# Notify superclass about subclass creation

Tags: java

Is there any way how to automatically send notification from subclass to superclass **after subclass has been fully initialized** i. e. after finishing subclass constructor?

**MOTIVATION**

Base class has to provide some default methods that are working with list of class fields. Since subclass fields are accessible in parent class only after subclass creation, base class can't read these subclass fields in base class constructor. One solution is to read subclass fields at the begining of each base method which need to process these fields. Due of slow reflection, it is better to use lazy-initialization.

I'm curious if there is some **not widely known callback mechanism** in Java that will allow to define some "subclass-created-callback" so I would be able to initialize these fields without using lazy-initialization to achieve **better maintainability**.

I know it is possible to track deallocation of an object e. g. via `finalize()` or `ReferenceQueue` so I want to know If there is something similar for object creation.

**EXAMPLE**

Suppose you want to create an database `Entity` class (I know there are ORM based solution for this, but this is only for illustration of similar problems) which will be able to generate SQL statements like CREATE TABLE, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE based on entity's class fields. So base class would be responsible for reading of class fields and also for producing these statements. To create an entity one would need just to extend `Entity` and use some field annotations like `@Column`, `@Id`, `@AutoIncrement`, ...

```
class Entity {
    public String getCreateTableStatement() {
        // lazy-initialize list of class fields and produce statement...
    }

    public String getInsertPreparedStatement() {
        // lazy-initialize list of class fields and produce statement...
    }

    // update, delete, ...
}
```

Example of subclass

```
public Person extends Entity {
    @Id public int id;
    @Column public String name;
}
```

**AIM**

To replace lazy initialization be another pattern that will help to reduce amount of repeated code. Ideally, subclass would not have to define anything else, only just "`extends Entity`".

Comment: This question seems like a possible [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question. Base classes should be completely ignorant of child classes, and not everything should be solved using inheritance. Are you sure that composition wouldn't be better?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I would like to provide some default methods based on class fields for any subclass extened from given base class, thus inheritance is _in situ_, otherwise I would need to repeat the same methods at each subclass.

Comment: Or you could have both classes be subclasses of the same parent class, but still have them related by composition. There are likely many ways to skin this fish.

Comment: How does one obtain a reference to a subclass object before the constructor has finished?

Comment: @laune base class is accessing subclas fields in methods i. e. at a time of any subclass construction. I think I will edit my question to provide more info about motivation.

Comment: Suggestion: make your question much less theoretical and instead much more *concrete*, including a small [mcve] real code example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sounds very much like what you want is just a callback. The inheritance structure seems irrelevant.

Comment: Looking at your example: why don't you just initialize your statements lazy?

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath that is exactly what I'm doing. I just wanted to know, if there is some callback mechanism which will help to avoid repeating of lazy-initialization.

Comment: You mean for every instance of the subclass? In this case, a static cache for the statements (mapping concrete subclass to a set of statements) would work.

Comment: @matoni What about reflection? Isn't it just a `this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` call to get all the fields you need?

Comment: @Progman I'm already using reflection. It seems that my question is still unclear, I will try to make some edits.

Comment: @matoni Show us the code you already have, specially how you already use reflection for reading/writing the fields of the (sub)class.

Comment: @Progman sorry, but I don't think code about fields reading is important here. This question is more about concept how to avoid lazy initialization (if possible), when subclass attributes (regardles how they are read) need to be acessed from the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you're trying to do, but in general, many problems that have to do with object creation can be solved by using a [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) that encapsulates the creational process. This way, you can do more than you can achieve in a single constructor call:

```
public static MySubClass createSubClass() {
    MySubClass subClass = new MySubClass();
    subClass.baseClassMethodThatManipulatesFields();
    return subClass;
}
```

Note that (as others have pointed out), inheritance might not be the best solution for your problem. The methods you list in `Entity` should probably be at the responsibility of the factory that uses reflection for initializing the class.

Comment: This is answer does not answer the question whether Java supports some creation callbacks, However I like this solution so I will probably accept this answer after a few days. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think such constructor callbacks exist in Java, but you can of course bake one in into a factory method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not asking why. If you want to do exactly like in you answer, then parent object has full access to it's children via constructor. Yes, I know that child object is not fully initialized at this time, but annotation informations is available at this step.

This is an example:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.MethodUtils;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class Entity {
        protected Entity() {
            List<AccessibleObject> ids = getAccessibleObjectWithAnnotation(Id.class);
            List<AccessibleObject> columns = getAccessibleObjectWithAnnotation(Column.class);
        }

        private List<AccessibleObject> getAccessibleObjectWithAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> cls) {
            List<AccessibleObject> res = new ArrayList<>();
            res.addAll(FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation(getClass(), cls));
            res.addAll(MethodUtils.getMethodsListWithAnnotation(getClass(), cls));
            return res;
        }
    }
```